# Using compression to improve edit distance computation

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, string-matching, edit-distance

I am doing a seminar on a paper titled ["Unified Compression-Based Acceleration
of Edit-Distance Computation"](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oweimann/Publications/SLP2.pdf) that uses straight-line programs to improve edit distance computation. It is a common method to exploit repetitions for ED although I couldn't find the first article that used it and I thought it is important to mention it in the seminar.

Does anybody have a clue what it was?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you consider the article by Masek and Paterson as the first one that used repetitions?

Comment: Please clarify: SLP = straight-line program?

Comment: I think I will consider it as the first though I am not sure it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crochemore, Landau and Ziv-Ukelson were, I believe, the first to consider (LZ) compression explicitly in this context. As mentioned in the comments above, the earlier technique of Masek and Paterson is also in effect a form of compression. Considering general grammar-compression (SLP) is, I believe, a relatively new idea. Using it for string comparison speedup is original to the paper you cite, although comparing grammar-compressed strings as such has been considered before. You will find references and discussion in the compression chapter of http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.3619 .

Comment: Wow, what an honor, an answer by Alexander Tiskin :). Your answer is probably correct but eventually I didn't mention it since a week ago I wasn't 100% sure who it really was. The lecture went good anyway. Thank you for the detailed answer!